# Showing only 5 post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, thumbnails, show

HI I have edited and make a template page of responsive theme to make some thumbnails of the features pics of the posts.
ALl it's okay I can see them, but even if the posts are 9 I could see only 5. If I add one ony I see the new one, there is something like "show only latest 5 posts" but I can't understand WHERE!

```
get_header(); ?>
```

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-header' ); ?>

        <?php responsive_entry_before(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>       
            <?php responsive_entry_top(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'post-meta-page' ); ?>



            <div class="post-entry">
                <?php the_content(__('Read more &#8250;', 'responsive')); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __('Pages:', 'responsive'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
            </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->
```

```
        (this is my added code) 
                            <ul>
            <?php  
            $posts = get_posts();
                foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

                ?>
                <li><div class="fotoBoxContent"><a class="fotoBox" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); the_title(); ?></a></div></li>
            <?php  endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
```

---

```
            <?php responsive_entry_bottom(); ?>      
        </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->       
        <?php responsive_entry_after(); ?>

        <?php responsive_comments_before(); ?>
        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
        <?php responsive_comments_after(); ?>

    <?php 
    endwhile; 

    get_template_part( 'loop-nav' ); 

else : 

    get_template_part( 'loop-no-posts' ); 

endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=NUMBER_GOES_HERE' );` immediately before the `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Replacing `NUMBER_GOES_HERE` with the amount of posts you want displayed. Use `-1` to show all posts

Also within Wordpress itself Settings->Reading has a field where you can set `Blog pages show at most`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what exactly you want to achieve but if you just want to have thumbnails of posts that are in the main loop, then you do not need to do additional query.

All you need to do is something like this:

1.) Before `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` you initialize some variable:

```
$thumb_data='';
```

2.) After `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>`

```
$thumb_data='<ul>';
```

3.) replace your "added code" with this:

```
$thumb_data.='<li><div class="fotoBoxContent"><a class="fotoBox" href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail()." ".get_the_title().'</a></div></li>';
```

4.) After the main while loop, add:

```
 $thumb_data='</ul>';
```

5.) Mow all the HTML code for the list of thumbnails will be in `$thumb_data`, so just echo this variable in the template where you want the HTML code to appear.

Comment: I have tried but it replicates the thumbnails. I have add the code in the first loop but nothing and in the second too (the second it's the code I have added fot get the posts info) but nothing too. Tried with WP settings but nothing too. You can see it [here](http://www.simonemontaresi.com/wordpress/linteabozza/products/). f you try you can see in the menu more than 5 posts, you cansee all of them in the slide too but not in the thumbnails

Comment: Do you want to display thumbnails of posts in the main loop?

Comment: You can see in the cose where is the thumbnail loop and the result, but only 5 are showed